# Borders show up on pdf document, but not from preview

Tags: microsoft-word

I exported a word doc to pdf and when I look at it from a PDF previewer, it shows dark lines around my text boxes.

I don't see those lines in word or preview and I got rid of fills for the objects.

Where are they coming from?

Details about my system -

Word version 16.40, most up to date preview on mac (it shows up fine there), in the gmail pdf viewer (it shows up with weird lines). OS is most up to date macbook

Also- the lines appear viewable from mac preview when I choose "best for electronic distribution" when exporting to pdf

Comment: Version of Word,  which pdf viewer, OS… etc etc? As it stands this is unanswerable. We cannot see over your shoulder, you have to tell us.

Comment: Please add relevant details to your question, not as comments. Be precise.

Comment: Some screenshots would also help.

Comment: Is there not much content in the word text box? Or there is no other content near the text box in word typesetting?